# Priority in core.match patterns

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching, core.match

In my core.match patterns I want one specific pattern to have a "high priority". For example in:

```
(match 
[paragraph line     text     is-special ]
[_      _   #"^\s*$" _      ] "empty"       
[0      0   _    false      ] "project-header"
[0      _   _    false      ] "project-header-note"
[1      _   _    false      ] "next-action"
[2      _   _    false      ] "following-action"
:else "generic"))
```

I want the `text` variable in the `"empty"` row to always stop subsequent matching if it matches and return "empty". However probably because this clause is more generic it tries it as the last one and matches another one instead.

Answer (score 3):

core.match's support for regexes lives in a separate namespace, `clojure.core.match.regex`. You'll need to require it **before your function gets compiled** for it to work the way you'd expect. The simplest, easiest and least error-prone way to do it is to add an appropriate `:require` clause to the `ns` clause of the namespace that you define your function in.

Also, pattern matching always tries the clauses in order. If you get a return value from a different clause than you expected, that means that that clause in fact failed to match your argument.

Comment: I should add that I tested this with core.match 0.2.0-rc3, which is the latest version available from Maven Central at this time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, core.match doesn't support regexes as match variables in any "special" way. That is, your first clause might match if `text` were actually a regex, but if it is a string *matching* a regex, it will fail.

Comment: Actually it does, but you need to `require` the appropriate namespace. Just posted an answer with the details.